# Home LAN Setup - Poor transfer rate

Tags: networking, lan, cat6, cat5e, coaxial

Trying to setup local LAN in my home. Have Verizon 1GB FIOS connection (**CR1000A** router) coming in using ethernet cable to the main router.Have an extender(Model **E3200**)  in the basement that has GB LAN ports as well. The main router and extender is connected via **COAX** cable.

[Verizon Extender](https://www.verizon.com/business/resources/factsheets/fios-extender-data-sheet-business.pdf)

[Verizon Main Router](https://scache.vzw.com/dam/support/pdf/user_guide/cr1000a-verizon-router-user-guide.pdf)

I have my Desktop and laptop connected to the main router. I did a **iperf** test on my desktop from my laptop . I received **900+ MBits/s** bandwidth and **110 MBytes** transfer speed on a wired connection (cat6a).

Then I connected my laptop to the extender (on basement) and ran another test against Desktop. This time I got only **350+ MBits/sec** bandwidth and **40+ Mbytes** transfer speed on wired connection(cat6a).

Is this normal? I think the coax cable is the bottleneck, its an older wiring (15+ years at least). I think if I replace coax with Cat5/6, the speed might improve. Any tips?
I do lot of 4K video streaming and gaming. So at least **100Mb** transfer speed would be beneficial.
What are my options? Should I get Cat5e/Cat6/Cat7 for the upgrade?Probably needs less than 50 feet wire.

Comment: I have RG6 COAX outside to house and inside to cable modem. It has been there for 30 years and supports Internet that I pay for of 400 Mbits/sec down and 30 Mbits/sec up. I don't think your coax is the bottleneck. And you do not replace coax with CAT5 or 6 Ethernet as a drop in replacement.

Comment: @John - I am talking about connecting router and extender using Cat6 instead of Coax. The inside wiring to the main router from Verizon box outside  is Ethernet cable already. I should be getting the same speed at both router and extender.

Comment: CAT5e is fast enough for home high LAN speeds.  You can also use CAT 6.    You should clarify your post

Comment: @John-  I agree, my previous place had cat5e and it worked just fine.

Comment: What I do here is use a simple but reliable cable tester and test / remake any questionable terminations as well as routing and kinks

Answer (score 1):

Your Verizon boxes are using a technology called MoCA 2.5 to communicate with each other over the pre-existing coaxial cables in your house. MoCA 2.5 is capable of 2.5Gbps under ideal conditions, but the left over coaxial cable TV, satellite TV, or TV antenna cable in most houses is usually not a great medium.

If installing Ethernet cable is feasible, run Ethernet! May as well pull Cat6a if you're pulling new cable in 2023, so that you have more options at 10Gbps and beyond.

If you don't want to do the home-improvement project of installing new Ethernet cables in your walls at this time, there are some potentially cheap and quick things you can do to optimize your coaxial cable tree for MoCA performance.

The first thing to do is to make sure you have a MoCA "Point of Entry" (PoE) filter connected at the top of your coaxial splitter hierarchy. Basically, this is where the coax cable from the cable TV company would come into your house, which is why it's called a "point of entry" filter. Putting a MoCA PoE filter at the top of your splitter hierarchy helps reflect MoCA signals back down into other parts of the splitter hierarchy, which helps with what MoCA designers call "splitter jumping" or "splitter traversal".

Another thing that can help MoCA signal problems is to look at all your coax splitters, and see what frequencies they're rated for. That information is usually stamped into the metal body of the splitter or printed on a label. If any of the splitters (at least the ones on the coax cable path between the two Verizon MoCA devices) is not rated for all the frequencies MoCA uses (which is up to something like 2GHz, if I recall correctly), then replace those splitters with "MoCA rated" splitters that are known to handle MoCA's frequencies well. MoCA uses frequencies well above 1GHz in order to avoid interfering with cable TV and DOCSIS. Cable TV and DOCSIS generally use frequencies from something like 5MHz up to a hair over 1GHz. Older splitters might not handle frequencies above 1GHz very well, and are thus a problem for MoCA.

If any of the coax cables (at least the ones in the path between MoCA devices) are easily accessible/replaceable, make sure those cables are high-quality quad-shielded RG6. You definitely want to replace those cables if they're RG-59.

And of course, make sure all of your coax cables are in good condition (no frayed shielding, no poorly-terminated connectors etc.) and that your connectors are tightly screwed together.

If you only look into one thing to try to improve your MoCA performance, make it the POE filter. In the vast majority of homes that report unsatisfactory MoCA performance, simply adding an inexpensive MoCA PoE filter was the only intervention that was needed.